# Can static IP communicate with floating IP?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS, wish someone can answer my stupid question.

I have a **static IP 140.113.xxx.xxx**, and a 4G dongle with **floating IP 192.168.8.100**.
I want to use ROS to ***transmit data between them***.
Can ROS do that? Because I found some website said ROS can only transmit data in the same Internet domain, but I think this must have some trick to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268193/can-static-ip-communicate-with-floating-ip?/) by [Henry1620](https://answers.ros.org/users/31460/henry1620/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS communications require that you have viable routes between both hosts. [Network Setup Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) Your "floating IP" is more accurately termed a NAT address and is not routable from outside. The most common solution to this is to put both machines on a VPN where your static IP can host the VPN server and the machine behind the 4G dongle can connect to the VPN via the static IP.

There's lots of advice for ROS + VPNs: https://www.google.com/search?q=ros+vpn

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2